# Joomla 3 LDAP username won't allow required special character

Tags: php, authentication

When using LDAP login authentication domain\username is the format that we need to use but Joomla will not allow this. When trying to save these users in Joomla backend the format is rejected due to the backslash that is used between the domain and username for the "Login Name."

> Error
>
> Save failed with the following error: Please enter a valid username. No space at beginning or end, at least 2 characters and must not contain the following characters: < > \ " ' % ; ( ) &

I would like to find a solution that does not require hacking the core so updates could still be done without having to re-modify the core.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need to insert the domain name before the username to get the LDAP to work.

AFAIR if the configuration is done correct (anonymous bind, DN) this should work. Anyway, it does require a bit of fiddling.

Also read the [Developer: LDAP from scratch](http://community.joomla.org/component/zine/article/507-developer-ldap-from-scratch-sam-moffatt.html)

Can you maybe post the configuration (obfuscating sensitive data)?